# How to update an element in spring boot using save method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, spring-data

I have two classes which have the following elements:

```
@Document(collection = "ClassP")
Class P{
@Id
private String p_id;
}

 @Document(collection = "ClassR")
Class R{
@Id
private String r_id;
private String item;

@DBRef
private P p;

@DBRef
private User user;
}
```

Here is my PRepository:

```
public interface PMongoRepository extends CrudRepository<P, String>{

P findPById(String p_id);
}
```

What I am going to do is to update the `item` from class R. I get the changed item from the frontend and in my controller I have the new item. So, there is no problem from the front end side.
In my controller, I have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editData", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
    public ModelAndView editData(@RequestBody Map<String, String> new_items) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

        R copyOfExistingR= new R();

        P pFound = pRepository.findPById(new_items.get("p_id"));
            copyOfExistingR.setP(pFound);
            copyOfExistingR.setItem(new_items.get("sep"));
            copyOfExistingR.setUser(user);
            rRepository.save(copyOfExistingR);

return modelAndView ;
}
```

But the code doesn't work as expected. On the `rRepository.save(copyOfExistingR);` I get the following error:

```
Cannot create a reference to an object with a NULL id.
```

The `pFound` is not null and I can print it out, but I don't know what I am doing wrong with updating the R class. I would be thankful if anybody could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had defined a variable above @Id in the P class and it was problematic. The @Id must always be the first item in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You never set id of copyOfExistingR.

Comment: I just tried that with directly setting the id (setId("something"), but unfortunately, it didn't help. Nevertheless, the current problem is about "/editData", I just checked my "/addData" and there I also haven't added any id.So, I think the id is added automatically. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is that you just set the *'r_id'***

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editData", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
        public ModelAndView editData(@RequestBody Map<String, String> new_items) {

            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();

            R copyOfExistingR = new R();

          //-----Here you set your r_id for object copyOfExistingR----

            P pFound = pRepository.findPById(new_items.get("p_id"));
                copyOfExistingR.setP(pFound);
                copyOfExistingR.setItem(new_items.get("sep"));
                copyOfExistingR.setUser(user);
                rRepository.save(copyOfExistingR);

    return modelAndView ;
    }
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't help. I added the id exactly at the place you have mentioned in your comment (right at the beginning).

Comment: First check 'pFound' is null or not.
And please share your modified code.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I used "copyOfCurrentReview.setId("something");" and "pFound" is not null. Fyi, I had exactly the same problem, when writing my code for /addData and at that time, the problem was solved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51943411/cannot-create-a-reference-to-an-object-with-a-null-id-mongo-hibernate-mongo-and
But this time, the instance of p class exists and I can't do the same process. I think there is something wrong with the logic of my code. Is that okay that I am working with a copy of the element and not directly on the  database?